# Accessing files from a multiple datastores on a VSAN in VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi, datastore

I have a VMware 6.7 environment running as a single datacenter, however with two clusters (say `A-cluster` and a `B-cluster`), each with 3 esxi hosts. A VSAN is configured on these clusters and has two VSAN datastrores (`A-datastore` and `B-datastore`) for `A-cluster` and `B-cluster` respectively.

Now, I have a iso file in the `A-datastore` and I'm trying to deploy a VM in B-cluster and in the process of deploying, I would like to mount the iso file present in the `A-datastore`. When I try to attach the CD/DVD and choose "Datastore ISO File" option, I only get to browse the `B-datastore`, but not the `A-datastore`.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 8):

The Virtual SAN datastores are ONLY presented to the hosts that are members of a particular cluster. But you can implement Content Library and store there all templates/iso/ etc.

Here is a detailed guide, how to create it - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/working-with-content-libraries-in-vsphere-6-5

Comment: Is the content library different from "Folders" that is typically created under the Hosts?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of Library is to share content accross different clusters. Folders are created for "local" usage inside one host/cluster.